# Colorbox modal not opening on Android / IOS

Tags: android, jquery, ios, colorbox, carousel

I have this this problem, with a html template - it's working fine on desktop if you open the portfolio modal, or news modal. On touchdevices IOS/Android the portfolio  opens the modal correctly but the news carousell does not open it at all . It's the same colorbox script for both.

Here is the original file

http://clapat.ro/themes/eleven/color/

Any feedback is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

It was the carouselfredsel script, that caused the issue. With swipe enabled on touchd, it ignored the "click" (tap).